# What is the unit of audio sample in librosa?

Tags: audio-processing, librosa

These days, I'm using librosa which is a kind of audio processing library. As a basic step to load audio files, one can use the function below.

```
librosa.core.load()
```

1. Then an audio file is represented as audio time series. I think each value of the time series is an amplitude of audio. However, I wonder what the unit of the amplitudes is.
2. Also, what is the relationship among amplitude, power, dB, and energy?

Comment: An SO question should only have 1 question/topic. Your second question is only tangentially related to the first, and likely has answers available already.

Answer (score 2):

`librosa.load` returns a numpy array of type `float32`, with values between `-1.0` and `1.0`. What physical quantity these values correspond to in the real world (or if they do at all) is unknown. So on its own, it is *unitless*.

If they file was recorded with a microphone, the values are linear with changes in air pressure. If you know the air pressure at time of recording (mean and min/max), you could map the values back to pressure (unit: Pascal).

Answer (score -1):

There are no defined units for amplitude in Librosa's docs. However, you can convert amplitude into decibel units using the following command: `librosa.amplitude_to_db(S, ref=1.0, amin=1e-05, top_db=80.0)`

Documentation for Librosa's magnitude functions can be found here: https://librosa.org/doc/main/core.html#magnitude-scaling

Comment: it would be worth noting that this decibels in a [`dBFS` scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS), not to be confused with analogue world [dB in any particular weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level).